# Nexus 6 vibrates 3 times quickly

Tags: nexus-6

Sometimes my Nexus 6 vibrates 3 times quickly, but there is no indication why in the Notification bar. Does anyone know why? I'm using Project Fi, so it could be related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've come up with an answer to my own question. Project Fi devices vibrate quickly 3 times every time the cellular radio connects to a wireless carrier.

Comment: Thanks for self-answering!  +1.  You should accept your answer by clicking the gray checkmark icon.